# How do I use a custom JOIN calculation to return only last two words from a value?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following dataset that I'm trying to import from SQL into Tableau

[image]

So I would want to go from the first column, to the second column:

[image]

So far I have the following custom query but it's only going off of characters:

```
STR (LEFT ([Membership Code], 5))
```

How could I change it to give me the desired results?

Comment: I’m unclear on the details of your question, but it sounds like Tableau’s SPLIT() function may be helpful to you.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to apply some string manipulation to extracts parts of the content in a string field. That is easy in tableau if the string has a standard structure. But I have no idea why doing anything at all with a JOIN would help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
Replace ([rollup_name], 'Organisation/HFT/USA/Z01/R01/D08/0053/', '')
```

Comment: I would be open to just replacing them because they are always going to be the same. However it wouldn't let me do that because it said replace doesn't work on an aggregate function

Comment: In that case, you have to tell us what your data structure is(not just a screenshot of filter dialogue box or some excel screenshot).  Without having a look on your data structure, it is nearly impossible to solve your problem

Comment: It's connected to a table in SQL. I can transform it in SQL with this:
 
SELECT substring(ROLLUP_NAME, 39, 20) as CUSTOM_DRIVER,
FROM   DNA_PUBLIC.ADMIN.SCHEDULE_EFFECTIVENESS

I was just wondering if there's a way to do this in Tableau

Comment: I think your fieldname is rollup_name and not membership code? Irrespective of whether you are fetching data from sql query you could share the data structure! And most importantly what is apparent from this sql query and dxcel screenshot, yes indeed this can be done in Tableau